# Perform operations at booting time in spring web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, grails

I have worked on grails and little on spring mvc.

Generally in our web application we need to do some operations at the time of application start or booting time, like creating admin users and roles if already not created OR loading some initial data.

Grails has provided this feature via BootStrap.grrovy file having init() and destroy() methods.

How can I achieve this functionality in spring web application ?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PostConstruct performs the task but acc to me it is not the perfect solution.

Another way of solving the problem is by handling [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) .

Event raised when an ApplicationContext gets initialized or refreshed.

Below is the code :

```
package a.b.c;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BootStrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event)
  {
    System.out.println("event object when context refreshed:"+event);
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = event.getApplicationContext();
    if( applicationContext.getParent()==null)
    {
      System.out.println("event object for rootApplicationContext object : "+event);
      bootApplicationData();
    }
  }

  private void bootApplicationData()
  {
    //operations you want to perform at loading time
  }
}
```

Output :

```
event object when context refreshed:org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent[source=Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 17 23:42:04 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy]
event object for rootApplicationContext object : org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent[source=Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 17 23:42:04 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy]

INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
event object when context refreshed:org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent[source=WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcherServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 17 23:42:13 IST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you annotate a method of one of your spring beans with `@PostConstruct` this method will be called after the application context has been created, e.g.

```
class MySpringBean {

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // initialization code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ContextLoaderListener,  Implement this interface and it will get called after the context is loaded.

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html